# MySQL Regex pattern for ***.leave this.*** doesnt work

Tags: mysql

What pattern to use to leave the characters between dots in string 
"12395.KS_TH014.001239" so what would be left only "KS_TH014", if  its dynamical var.
I tried pattern ".\K.*?(?=.)" but it doesnt work in mysql (mariadb 10.0.10 server)

Comment: Which datatype use for this column in mysql.

Comment: What's the version(`SELECT VERSION();`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no regex groups up and including [mysql-5.7](/questions/tagged/mysql-5.7). However one can use UDF(user defined function) to achieve similar behavior:

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST('12395.KS_TH014.001239', '[[.period.]].*[[.period.]]'), '[[.period.]]', '');
```

The function below replaces the leftmost regex in a string:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION REGEX_REPLACE(var_original VARCHAR(1000), var_pattern VARCHAR(1000),
                                                         var_replacement VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
    COMMENT 'Based on https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/'
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_replaced VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT var_original;
  DECLARE var_leftmost_match VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT
    REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(var_original, var_pattern);
    WHILE var_leftmost_match IS NOT NULL DO
      IF var_replacement <> var_leftmost_match THEN
        SET var_replaced = REPLACE(var_replaced, var_leftmost_match, var_replacement);
        SET var_leftmost_match = REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(var_replaced, var_pattern);
        ELSE
          SET var_leftmost_match = NULL;
        END IF;
      END WHILE;
  RETURN var_replaced;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

which depends on:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(var_original VARCHAR(1000), var_pattern VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
    COMMENT '
  Captures the leftmost substring that matches the [var_pattern]
  IN [var_original], OR NULL if no match.
  '
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_temp_l VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE var_temp_r VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE var_left_trim_index INT;
  DECLARE var_right_trim_index INT;
  SET var_left_trim_index = 1;
  SET var_right_trim_index = 1;
  SET var_temp_l = '';
  SET var_temp_r = '';
  WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(var_original) >= var_left_trim_index) DO
    SET var_temp_l = LEFT(var_original, var_left_trim_index);
    IF var_temp_l COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci REGEXP var_pattern COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci THEN
      WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(var_temp_l) >= var_right_trim_index) DO
        SET var_temp_r = RIGHT(var_temp_l, var_right_trim_index);
        IF var_temp_r COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci REGEXP var_pattern COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci THEN
          RETURN var_temp_r;
          END IF;
        SET var_right_trim_index = var_right_trim_index + 1;
        END WHILE;
      END IF;
    SET var_left_trim_index = var_left_trim_index + 1;
    END WHILE;
  RETURN NULL;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```